# Porque no puedo asignar de esta manera en C?

Tags: c, gcc

Estoy aprendiendo punteros y tengo estas dudas....

1. Entiendo que la asignación de puntero a puntero se hace de esta manera.

int *p ,*q, a;
q=&a;
p=q

Porque cuando es un puntero que apunta a otro puntero, no lo puedo asignar de la misma forma

```
int A, *P , **PP;
A = 10;
P = &A;
PP = P;
```

Entiendo que P es una direccion de memoria al igual que PP
El error que me tira es "assignment to 'int **' from incompatible pointer type 'int *'

Luego, por error en el tipeo se me genero esta otra duda...

Porque no puedo asignar de esta manera:

```
int A, *P , **P;
```

El error que da es "Error confligtin types for P"

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un puntero es una variable que almacena una dirección de memoria y se denota anteponiendo un `*` al nombre. El más simple es `void*`. El operador `&` obtiene la dirección de memoria de una variable.

Por ejemplo:

```
int a = 10;
void* ptr = &a;
*ptr = 5; // Error
```

Sucede que un puntero de tipo `void` no puede ser desreferenciado (leer o escribir en la dirección de memoria a la que apunta) porque la memoria contiene simplemente **1**s y **0**s. Necesita del tipo para saber como debe interpretar esa información además que cada tipo tiene un tamaño diferente.

En lugar de `void` escribes el tipo correspondiente:

```
int a = 10;
int* ptr = &a;
*ptr = 5; // Ahora sí puedes
```

---

Para definir un puntero a un puntero también antepones un `*` al nombre. En este ejemplo el tipo del puntero es `int*`. Por lo tanto el tipo del puntero al puntero (valga la redundancia) es `int**`.

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
int* ptr = &a;
int** ptr2 = &ptr;

*ptr = 5; // Como "ptr" apunta a "a", a = 5
*ptr2 = &b; // Como "ptr2" apunta a "ptr", ahora "ptr" apunta a "b"
*ptr = 8; // b = 8
```

Como puedes ver la complejidad del programa aumenta con cada nivel de indirección que agregas.